# Gutenberg — block query loop — how to sort custom post type by its taxonomies?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using Gutenberg and some custom post type.
I want to know if it's possible to filter CPT by its custom taxonomies. Not only the categories and tags from WP core.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out too. The custom taxonomy is not appearing in the filter section of the panel inspector and I can't find relevant documentation about this particular problem.